# How to use pyftsubset of Fonttools inside of the python environment, not from the command line

Tags: python, fonts, ttx-fonttools

I need to subset very many font files and I need to do that from within the python environment. Yet, Fonttools is very poorly documented and I cannot find a module and the proper function syntax to perform subsetting based on unicode from within python, not as a command line tool (`pyftsubset`). Some of my files contain various errors when read by the Fonttools and I cannot catch exceptions using `!command` inside jupyter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pyftsubset` is itself just a Python script, which calls `fontTools.subset.main`, which in turn parses `sys.argv` (command-line args) to perform subsetting. You can do the same thing pretty easily in your own script, for example:

```
import sys
from fontTools.subset import main as ss

sys.argv = [None, '/path/to/font/file.ttf', '--unicodes=U+0020-002F']
ss()  # this is what actually does the subsetting and writes the output file
```

Obviously you'll want to use your own values for `--unicodes` plus the numerous other `pyftsubset` options, but in general this scheme should work. Possible caveat is if you have other parts of your program that use/rely on `sys.argv`; if that's the case you might want to capture the initial values in another variable before modifying `sys.argv` and calling the subsetter, then re-set it to the initial values after.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Is it actually possible to run it more elegantly, i.e. access the function that actually does the subsetting? I checked the source code and the subset module's `__main__.py` references itself somehow. Here, `from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import
from fontTools.misc.py23 import *
import sys
from fontTools.subset import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())`

Comment: The way to do that would be to create your own `fontTools.subset.Subset` object, and populate it with the values you want, then call that object's `subset()` method on a `fontTools.ttLib.TTFont` object that you create...all of which, to me, anyway, seems _less_ elegant than simply setting `sys.argv` with well-documented command-line options, then calling `fontTools.subset.main()` with a font path.

Answer (score 4):

I think that should be a pythonic way to do it properly:

```
from fontTools import subset
subsetter = subset.Subsetter()
subsetter.populate(unicodes=["U+0020", "U+0021"])
subsetter.subset(font)
```

While `font` is your TTFont and you might need to check the documentation for how to exactly pass in the the list of unicodes. I didn’t test this exact code, but I tested it with `subsetter.populate(glyphs=["a", "b"])` which does a similar job, but with glyphNames instead. The `populate` method can take these arguments as documented: `populate(self, glyphs=[], gids=[], unicodes=[], text='')`

I found a clue to that in [this discussion](https://github.com/googlefonts/fontbakery/issues/437).

Comment: Note that the way to instantiate `font` is `font = subset.load_font("path/to/font", options)` where `options` is a `subset.Options`; defaults can be had with `subset.load_font("path/to/font", subset.Options())`

Answer (score 2):

In 2023 the proper way how to call fonttools subset from python is to use standard interface, similar to command line:

```
from fontTools import subset

args = [
    "font.woff2",
    "--unicodes=5f-7a,30-39,e8a6,e1b1,e5cf,e15b,e5c4,e8fd",
    "--no-layout-closure",
    "--output-file=./out.woff2",
    "--flavor=woff2",
]

subset.main(args)
```